# Pandas: Why should appending to a dataframe of floats and ints be slower than if its full of NaN

Tags: python, casting, pandas

I am taking data from a file that receives data from Interactive Brokers 5-second OHLCVT bars via Sierra Chart.

Following advice in earlier posts, rather than append each new row to the dataframe I construct a dataframe with the historical file and append 5000 "blank" records to it with correct timestamps.  I then write each new row over a blank row, filling any rows if timestamps are missing and updating pointers.

This works well.  Here's the current [classes and functions](http://pastebin.com/yc4i95EX).  My initial version created 5000 lines of NaNs (OHLCVxyz).  I thought it would be tidier to start with the end data types so converted the "blank" records to zeros with OHLC being floats and Vxyz being ints using:

```
dg.iloc[0:5000] = 0.0
dg[[v, x, y, z]] = dg[[v, x, y, z]].astype('int')
```

This only occurs once per additional 5000 lines (once a day for HSI).  What surprised me was the impact on the read/write loops.  They went from 0.8ms to 3.4ms per row.  The only change was from NaNs to zeros.

[This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXLK0.png) shows an inital run with a zero filled frame (see timestats 0.0038) then a run with a NaN filled frame (timestats 0.0008).

Can anyone provide insight on why it might add so much time to write to fields of [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0] instead of [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN] ?

Any thoughts on code improvements are also welcome. :)

Thanks

> 

**EDIT** +17 hours

Following the questions from @BrenBarn I built a simpler model that could be run by anyone without data.  In doing so I eliminated the question of whether the NaNs impact it.  In this version I was able to write 0.0s to both versions and the difference was the same:

- the array that has 8 columns of floats is added to 10 times faster than the array that has 4 columns of floats and 4 of int64s.
- in each case the row being added was [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5, 6, 7, 8]
- the add is done 10000 times with self.df.iloc[self.end] = datarow and increment end.

So, unless I'm mistaken (always possible) it seems that adding to a dataframe with 4 columns of floats and 4 of ints takes 10x as long.  Is this an issue for pandas or just what one should expect?

[Here's the test code](http://pastebin.com/8dbNr7TU)
and [here is the output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omGkA.png)

I think that having an array of 350,000 rows of 8 columns before you add to it makes a significant difference.  My initial tests adding to 10 rows showed no impact - I must go back and retest them.

> 

**EDIT** +10 minutes

No I went back and created the intial array with only 10 rows and the impact on the add loops didn't change so its not the size of the original array/dataframe.  Its probable that in my earlier test I thought I'd converted the columns to ints but I hadn't - checking this proved that the command I thought would do this didn't.

```
da = SierraFrame(range(10), np.zeros((10,8)))
da.extend_frame1()
```

> 

**EDIT and Possible Answer** +35 minutes

Should this question not be answered in more detail.

At this point, my **hypothesis** is that the underlying functionality to add [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5, 6, 7, 8] to a spare line in the dataframe is different if the df comprises all one type than if it comprises columns of floats and ints.  I just tested it with all int64s and the average add was 0.41ms vs 0.37ms for all floats and 2.8ms for a mixed dataframe. Int8s took 0.39ms.  I guess that the mix affects pandas ability to optimize its action **so if efficiency is very important then a dataframe with all columns being the same type (float64 probably) is the best bet.**

*Tests conducted on Linux x64 with Python 3.3.1*

Comment: What is the type of the data you are writing into those cells?  Also, what exactly are you timing?  Is it possible that the setting of the zeros itself is part of what's being timed?

Comment: The setting of zeros/type casting takes place when the existing file is read and the frame is created.  After that a loop starts the timer (each iteration) tests for new data and if there is data converts it to a list called datarow with four floats and four integers which is written over the current row of the dataframe using self.df.iloc[self.end] = datarow. The change to the dataframe is also written out to a file.  Only if there was data is the current time difference appended to time_list to create statistics.

Comment: To eliminate the possibility that the file write after the read and conversion might have impacted it I commented it out.  This reduces both results by ~ 0.4 ms.

Comment: can you exactly what you are doing; both of these cases (0-filled or nan filled) time the same

Comment: I created a test version that generates a df from a numpy array, then appends 10,000 rows for filling with incoming (dummy) data.  This is described in the Edit and you could run it yourself to see if case 1 (writing to df of float 0.0s) differs from case 2 (writing to df with half the columns float 0 and half of them int64 0).

I greatly appreciate your questions ... they have driven me to simplify the test as much as possible.

Comment: This is question is now quite long, I recommend actually editing rather than appending edits, this way you can rewrite the earlier parts (which I think do need some work). At the moment it's too difficult to work out your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I need to reconsider how much I am likely to learn and decide how to proceed. I was not aware of this approach at stackoverflow.

If I do I will probably ask as new question and provide new, simpler code to demonstrate the issue.

Basically, now the question is very simple:
- why do different types in the columns of a dataframe make it slower to add a list to an existing row (floats and ints vs floats only)?

Answer (score 5):

As described in [this blog post by the main author of pandas](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?s=BlockManager), a pandas DataFrame is internally made up of "blocks".  A block is a group of columns all having the same datatype.  Each block is stored as a numpy array of its block type.  So if you have five int columns and then five float columns, there will be an int block and a float block.

Appending to a multi-type array requires appending to each of the underlying numpy arrays.  Appending to numpy arrays is slow, because it requires creating a whole new numpy array.  So it makes sense that appending to a multi-type DataFrame is slow: if all the columns are one type, it only has to create one new numpy array, but if they're different types, it has to create multiple new numpy arrays.

It is true that keeping the data all the same type will speed this up.  However, I would say the main conclusion is not "if efficiency is important, keep all your columns the same type".  The conclusion is **if efficiency is important, do not try to append to your arrays/DataFrames**.

This is just how numpy works.  The slowest part of working with numpy arrays is creating them in the first place.  They have a fixed size, and when you "append" to one, you really are just creating an entirely new one with the new size, which is slow.  If you absolutely must append to them, you can try stuff like messing with types to ease the pain somewhat.  But ultimately you just have to accept that any time you try to append to a DataFrame (or a numpy array in general), you will likely suffer a substantial performance hit.

Comment: Thanks for that BrenBarn.  I can see that @Jeff is right and my original question has become too long.  In fact I only append every 5000 rows and the loop being timed is actually writing data into a row appended when the main file was read to create the dataframe.

Comment: The add is done with self.df.iloc[self.end] = datarow where datarow is always a list of 4 floats and 4 ints.  However your answer does explain why writing it over the existing row would take an order of magnitude longer - it seems likely that pandas has to use code suited to write the list to two different arrays rather than one (all floats) array - perhaps the code is not as optimized.  I am going to try one more thing:  adding 4 floats to the first half and 4 ints to the second half as two separate writes to see what the timing becomes.

Comment: @John9631: The same logic applies, though.  If you write data to a DataFrame with multiple types, it actually has to do two writes to two separate numpy arrays.  I wouldn't expect this slowdown to be as much as the append, but it still does involve two separate numpy operations instead of one.

Comment: I tried splitting the write so that I wrote a list of 4 to the 4 blank floats and then 4 to the 4 blank ints using the code below but the result was identical.  So it seems it must be that this operation on the multi-type array is just much slower.  Thanks for the information. ... ... ...
        self.df.iloc[self.end, 0:4]=[1.0 , 2.0, 3.0, 4.0] ...
        self.df.iloc[self.end, 4:8]=[11, 12, 13, 14]

Comment: Oops ... I see you'd replied.  I have done the experiment and shown that you are right :)

... Where speed is important I will use single type dataframes to allow Wes (and team)'s optimizations to work their best.