# Save pandas dataframe to disk work by row

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas has [many output formats](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html). Which of these is best suited for iteratively appending rows to a dataframe and having them written to disk immediately - so that if the program or machine crashes, the last computed row is still saved and the resulting data file is not corrupt?

I was unable to find examples for this functionality in the docstrings of the individual `to_*()` functions.

Comment: generally, you shouldn't append rows to dataframes repeatedly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141828/pandas-why-should-appending-to-a-dataframe-of-floats-and-ints-be-slower-than-if

Comment: Convincing. So say I know how long my df will be, and create it first off - what would be the best way to save the dataframe anew after each iteration of adding values to one more row?

Comment: how big is the dataframe? if you're willing to save the whole thing each time, you could just do something like `df.dropna().to_*()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.HDFStore.append()` or `df.to_hdf(path, 'table_name', append=True)` - see [HDF docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables), and [`.append()` docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.HDFStore.append.html)

Usage example would be, with `df` representing a single row:

```
df.to_hdf('store.h5','table',append=True)
```

or

```
pd.HDFStore('store.h5).append('table_name', df)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to write a custom generator that writes to disk before yielding to the DataFrame

```
data = [(0,1,'a'), (0,2,'b'), (1,2,'c')]
def writeGen(data_tuples):
    with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
        for data in data_tuples:
            string = ','.join(str(c) for c in data) + '\n'
            f.write(string)
            yield data

pd.DataFrame(writeGen(data))
```

The above writes the `csv` file as expectd andOutputs:

```
    0   1   2
0   0   1   a
1   0   2   b
2   1   2   c
```